# Factory to send xml strings over the wire

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, factory, xmlserializer

What I am going for is explained in the code...
but the jist of it is I want to read child classes persisted in xml:

```
abstract class Parent {
    virtual string ToXml()
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = XmlSerializer( typeof (this) );
        ...
        return xmlString;
    }

    virtual void FromXml(string rawXml)
    {
        //either memberwise copy or throw exception if wrong type
        ...
    }
}

sealed class Child1 : Parent
{
    [XmlElement("Prop1")] 
    public Property1 { get; set; }

    public Child1() { }
}

sealed class Child2 : Parent
{
    [XmlElement("Prop2")]
    public Property1 { get; set; }

    public Child2() { }
}

static void main()
{
    string flatChild1 = new Child1().ToXml();
    string flatChild2 = new Child2().ToXml();

    // some time goes by
    ...

    Child1 one = new Child1();
    Child2 two = new Child2();

    one.FromXml(flatChild1); //must be "child one" string or exception
    two.FromXml(flatChild2);

    //one.FromXml(flatChild2); !! invalid

    /*
      what i want is some sort of factory...

      sealed class MyFactory
      {
         static Parent MyFactory.FromXml(string xmlObject);
      }

    */
    Parent obj1 = MyFactory.FromXml(flatChild1);
    Parent obj2 = MyFactory.FromXml(flatChild2);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(obj1, Child1.GetType());
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(obj2, Child2.GetType());
}
```

** Edit **

I want to send xml over the wire, so something like this:

```
// Server.exe Project
server_SendChild1Message()
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF16.GetBytes( child1.ToXml() );
    server.tcpClient[0].write( data, 0, data.Length );
}

// Seperate Client.exe
client_ReadMessages()
{
    string s = getNextXmlMessage();
    //needs to create a Child1 or Child2 based on xml string
    BaseXmlObj b = Factory.objFromXml(s);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `[XmlInclude(...)]`? I just want to check before going on...

Comment: You're basically trying to create any type from XML you receive; unless you go through the effort of inspecting the XML and attempting to parse a type and then trying to deserialize as that type, this is doomed to failure.

Comment: No, I haven't thought of that. I looked it up on msdn, so i would embelish my base class with XmlInclude (allMyChildTypes) ? The point of this is I want to send xml over the wire and reconstruct it on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Generics. Does this work for what you are trying to do?

If you are trying to avoid specifing the type of the object to deserialize, you can't; it determines the code used to deserialize the object.

```
abstract class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T> {
    virtual string ToXml()
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = XmlSerializer( typeof (T) );
        ...
        return xmlString;
    }

    virtual void FromXml(string rawXml)
    {
        //either memberwise copy or throw exception if wrong type
        ...
    }
}

sealed class Child1 : Parent<Child1>
{
    [XmlElement("Prop1")] 
    public Property1 { get; set; }

    public Child1() { }
}

sealed class Child2 : Parent<Child1>
{
    [XmlElement("Prop2")]
    public Property1 { get; set; }

    public Child2() { }
}

static void main()
{
    string flatChild1 = new Child1().ToXml();
    string flatChild2 = new Child2().ToXml();

    // some time goes by
    ...

    Child1 one = new Child1();
    Child2 two = new Child2();

    one.FromXml(flatChild1); //must be "child one" string or exception
    two.FromXml(flatChild2);

    //one.FromXml(flatChild2); !! invalid

    /*
      what i want is some sort of factory...

      sealed class MyFactory<T>
      {
         static T MyFactory.FromXml(string xmlObject);
      }

    */
    Child1 obj1 = MyFactory<Child1>.FromXml(flatChild1);
    Child2 obj2 = MyFactory<Child2>.FromXml(flatChild2);

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(obj1, Child1.GetType());
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(obj2, Child2.GetType());
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use generic code here.  Replacing `typeof(T)` in `Parent.ToXml()` with `GetType()` works just as well.

Comment: Yes, that works for the sample code; however, if you need to make a factory class that will deserialize any class, then generics is the easiest way to generate deserialization types.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. The only input the factory could recieve is the raw xml.